# Java PreparedStatement using two single quotes for empty string parameter

Tags: java, sql, escaping, prepared-statement

I am using a `PreparedStatement` with sql such as:

```
String sql = "insert into foo (a,b,c) values (?,?,?)";
 ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

  ps.setString(psIndex++, a);
  ps.setString(psIndex++, b);
  ps.setString(psIndex++, c);
```

But if any of the variables is an empty string the resulting statement gets two single quotes. As in: `VALUES ('foo','','')`  Then I get an exception since two single quotes is an escape sequence.

I can't believe I couldn't find anything on this through searching, but I could not. What is going on here?

Comment: It could be a bug in the JDBC driver you are using.  The provider of the driver should know that '' is an escape sequence.  What driver/database are you using?  Also can you check for an empty string and inset Types.NULL instead?

Comment: Yeah, the driver seemed to do it.  I had some thing from back in 2000, the current one works just fine now.

Comment: I recommend you answer your own question describing your findings and how you resolved it. That way others with your same problem will benefit! :)

Answer (score 3):

*As the OP doesn't do what @Adam suggested in the comments, I'll do it. It's useful for future readers. Thanks to @user119179 for the idea.*

It could be a **bug in the JDBC driver** we are using. The provider of the driver should know that `''` is an escape sequence.

Actually, updating the driver seems to solve the bug for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

> As in: VALUES ('foo','','') Then I get an exception since two single quotes is an escape sequence.

There is a misunderstanding here. The two single quotes *is* the empty string. There is no escape sequence happening. It is an escaped quote only if it is in another single quote. If you are getting an exception, it is probably elsewhere, such as a constraint on the column in the database.

The statement

```
insert into foo (a,b,c) values ('foo','','')
```

is very valid SQL.

Answer (score 0):

@cyberkiwi is correct. May be your columns does not accept null values. What Exception are you getting ? If you have got any log reports then share it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace single quote `'` with UNICODE `\u2019` value.
For more details click on this [url](http://javamasterhelp.blogspot.in/2012/09/how-to-insert-values-with-single-quote.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have not shared your Java Exception & that would have helped in formulating a precise answer.

There are two aspects in your program - Java & DB Constraints.

For Java, Empty String is `""`  ( Its double quotes not single quotes ) so as long as your Java references - `a`, `b`  & `c` have this value when value is empty , I don't see any issue as far as `PreparedStatement` is concerned. You don't have to worry about single quote escape sequence if using `PreparedStatement`. I am not sure why you listing values as `['foo','','']` , it should be `["foo","",""]`.

Second aspect that your DB columns `a`, `b` & `c` might not allow empty values due to constraints is altogether a different thing and can't be controlled with Java code. DB Table Schema needs to be changed to allow default values in that case.

Discussion about single quote escape sequence is relevant when somebody is preparing SQL query by directly appending values in query string like ,  `"insert into foo (a,b,c) values ('foo','','')";`  or a `WHERE` clause with `a='foo'` . This way is not recommended though due to SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT:** As others pointed out, you should n't be doing anything special to pass empty string to a parametrized query.

But, **just in case** if you happen to be using Dynamic SQLs in a query like:

```
Declare sqlText VARCHAR(MAX)
set sqlText = 'SELECT ....'
EXEC(sqlText)
```

then you would need to escape each of the single quotes as `''''` to get an equivalent to an empty string. So, a total of 4 quotes. The first 2 single quotes would be equivalent to getting a single quote at runtime. Another 2 single quotes will get the closing quote at runtime.

Comment: This isn't what Andrew is asking about. He is using prepared statements, but the JDBC driver appears to be emitting the wrong SQL.

Comment: +1 to what Adam said. One of the points of using parameterized queries is to avoid having to worry about doing this yourself.